# When Im trying to add the dropdwon list from my main nav bar, my main nav bar alighment is changes

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vbn4g.png)
My Main Menu is went up when i added the drop-down values

Comment: HTML Code:
  <nav class="tm-nav">
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Technologies</a>
                        <ul><li><a href="#">Testing1</a></li></ul>
                        <ul><li><a href="#">Testing2</a></li></ul>
                        <ul><li><a href="#">Testing3</a></li></ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact me</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

Comment: Can you please provide us a jsfiddle? with your html and css. here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

I assume the main menu should be horizontal. Below a solution to display the sub-menu on hover of the main menu option.

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav>ul {
  display: flex;
}

nav>ul>li {
  padding: 1em;
}

nav>ul>li>ul {
  display: none;
}

nav>ul>li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="tm-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Technologies</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Testing1</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Testing2</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Testing3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact me</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```